# how to add input box on Android epub (ebooks)

Tags: android, epub

i have implemented a ebook on android .epub which is like quiz question and answers .
created a questions and add textbox for users to enter values for answers. while checking in safari its working fine but uploaded in google play store and checking the textbox are disabled and when clicking on text box which is not open keyboard in tablet.

Code:

```
<p class="number">1.&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Luke and his brothers were looking for horseshoe crabs in the swamp.<br/>Do you see the horseshoe crabs? What page can you find them on? <input type="color" name="Name" autofocus ="autofocus" onclick="iPadTouchHandler(event)" /><input type="text" class="sml_txt" value="sfsf" id="qs1" /><div class="qs1"><img src='../images/x_16.png' alt='image' class='qs1_wrong' /><img src='../images/tick_16.png' alt='image' class='qs1_tick' /></div></p>
```

for validating the input

```
$('#qs1').on('input', function() {   var qs1 = $('#qs1').val(); alert(qs1); });
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: <p class="number">1.&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Luke and his brothers were looking for horseshoe crabs in the swamp.<br/>Do you see the horseshoe crabs? What page can you find them on? <input type="color" name="Name" autofocus ="autofocus" onclick="iPadTouchHandler(event)" /><input type="text" class="sml_txt" value="sfsf" id="qs1" /><div class="qs1"><img src='../images/x_16.png' alt='image' class='qs1_wrong' /><img src='../images/tick_16.png' alt='image' class='qs1_tick' /></div></p>

for validating the input 
$('#qs1').on('input', function() {   
var qs1 = $('#qs1').val();
alert(qs1);
});

Comment: i paste my code above.

Comment: Help you put the code into question.

Comment: why the textbox is not accepted in epub files it visible but if we touch the box there is no action on it. even the keyboard of tablet is not visbile , how can i fix this, how to show the keyboard on tablet what to add for this.